# Is there an english word that describes: hopefully-to-be?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that says "hopefully-to-be." Meaning someone is hoping that a new store will be opened.

> "The ___________ [hopefully-to-be] store would be right next to my house"

Comment: "eagerly anticipated" is often used in those cases.  It does suggest there is almost an expectation that it will happen though.

Comment: the *hoped-for* store...

Answer (score 2):

***Prospective*** may work here.

> "The ***prospective*** store would be right next to my
>   house."

M-W:

> **[prospective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prospective)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **2 a** :  likely to come about :  expected

Usage examples:
[Google search for "prospective store"](https://www.google.com/search?q="prospective+store")

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***desired***.

e.g. "The **desired** store would be right next to my house."

I like it better than "eagerly anticipated" for the reason Tom22 mentioned -- it doesn't imply the strong expectation, simply a wish that it would be.